# admin panel doesn't work properly

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I've added a module to my website and ran those commands

```
php bin\magento setup:upgrade
php bin\magento setup:di:compile
php bin\magento setup:static-cotent:deploy
php bin\magento cache:flush
```

since then admin panel sidebar doesn't respond and when I've tried to log in to admin panel from another browser it has no style

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when admin has no style loaded is either **Cloudflare** (or similar) service issue, or you need to delete the static contents manually.

1. Flush Cloudflare (or similar) cache and see if it resolves the issue
2. Depending on the M2 version:

version < 2.2.x

```
cd <MAGENTO_INSTALL_DIR>
rm -rf var/generation/* 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* 
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

version >= 2.2.x

```
rm -rf generated/* 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* 
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

re-run the Magento deploy commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento setup:di:compile  
php bin/magento setup:static-cotent:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

> rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf pub/static/* && php
>   bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme
>   Magento/backend -f